# PHP Simple XML Element Object - How to get string value

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

How do I get the values of the follow array fields in php? When I do a print_r function on a two dimensional array, I get the following result:

```
[title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [date] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

How do I get the string value of title and date? I've tried casting them with

> (string)

, however this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the attributes of the SimpleXMLElement Object.
Say you have an instance named entry with child title you type

```
(string) $entry->title;
```